# Enviar objetos via socket

Tags: java, socket

Eu tenho um chat que troca mensagens (`String`) entre si. Tudo está funcionando corretamente. Porém, agora, quero começar a enviar objetos via `Socket`, como por exemplo, uma classe que tem alguns atributos setados por mim (ex: nome, IP, *host name*, hora, mensagem, etc).

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Quando uso apenas `String`, para receber os dados, eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(servidor.getInputStream());
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            cliente.writeHistorico(s.nextLine());
        }
```

E para enviar:

```
  PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  ps.println("mensagem aqui);
```

PS: Lembrando que sempre estão dentro de threads e em LOOP.
Até aí, sem segredo. Porém, quando vou fazer para ler um objeto:

```
        readObject = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        User s = (User) readObject.readObject();
```

Como vou fazer verificar se o cliente enviou ou não dados para o servidor? Já que dessa maneira, eu não tenho por exemplo, um "`hasNext()`". Porque se eu deixar um `while(true)`, com a instância de `ObjectInputStream` fora, ele não funciona, e se deixar dentro do loop vai ficar criando várias instâncias. Tem alguma maneira de isso? Acho que enrolei um pouco, mas é isso. Já procurei material na net e todos os exemplos possíveis mostram sem usar loop com **UM** cliente conectado, até mesmo na documentação de sockets mostra apenas como trocar mensagens (`String`) e apenas um usuário..

**EDITADO:**

Fiz um exemplo bem básico. Classe de ler objetos do servidor:

```
    public class ThreadRecebedor extends Thread implements Runnable {

    InputStream inputCliente;
    ObjectInputStream input;
    User user;

    public ThreadRecebedor(InputStream inputCliente) {
        this.inputCliente = inputCliente;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //while (true) {
                input = new ObjectInputStream(inputCliente);
                Object aux = input.readObject();
                if (aux instanceof User) {
                    user = (User) aux;
                    System.out.println(user.getNome());
                    System.out.println(user.getMsg());
                    System.out.println(user.getHora());
                }
              //  input.close();
           // }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ThreadRecebedor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Classe para enviar os dados:

```
       public class cliente {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("192.168.1.7", 1412);
            User user = new User();
            user.setNome("Teste");
            user.setMsg("oi cristiano");
            user.setHora(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            output.writeObject(user);
            output.flush();
            output.reset();
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Da maneira como estão as duas classes, está funcionando. O servidor consegue ler o objeto enviado e mostra no console as propriedades. Mas agora vem o ponto chave: E se eu quiser repassar esses dados para o próprio usuário? Dessa maneira, o socket dele vai estar fechado. E se eu quisesse ficar escutando esse cliente para outros objetos? Como eu faria? 
Eu juro que li seu comentário umas 3x, mas não consegui entender como fazer isso que quero. Me desculpe pela ignorância.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em teoria, é perfeitamente possível se escrever e ler vários objetos serializados numa mesma stream. Na prática, me lembro de já ter esbarrado numa série de problemas no passado, e não me recordo bem dos mesmos (nem de suas soluções). Pessoalmente, eu serializaria esses objetos num outro formato (digamos, XML ou JSON) e os passaria no formato texto mesmo, simplificando sua vida.

Dito isso, aqui vão algumas sugestões (alternativas) caso você ainda queira fazer dessa maneira:

- Coloque seus objetos em um `Object[]`, e mande **isso** (simples, mas só se o lado escritor já sabe sua quantidade antes de enviar).
- Antes de enviar seus objetos, envie um número dizendo quantos objetos serão enviados (idem).
- Use um objeto especial para indicar "fim da transmissão"; continue lendo até encontrar esse objeto. Você teria, é claro, que verificar o tipo desse objeto antes de fazer *cast* para o tipo `User`.

  ```
  readObject = new ObjectInputStream(input);
  boolean acabou = false;
  do {
      Object lido = readObject.readObject();
      if ( lido instanceof User ) {
          User s = (User)lido;
          // Faz alguma coisa com o User s (ex.: adicione-o a uma lista)
      }
      else if ( lido instanceof FimTransmissao )
          acabou = true;
  } while(!acabou);
  // Opcional: input.close();
  ```
- Tente ler, e se encontrar uma exceção (normalmente EOF - indicando fim da stream) pare de ler. Código adaptado [dessa postagem no oracle.com](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2113555):

  ```
  readObject = new ObjectInputStream(input);
  int quantosObjetos = 0;
  boolean chegouAoFim = false;
  while (!chegouAoFim) {
      User s = null;
      try { 
          s = (User) readObject.readObject();
      }
      catch (EOFException eofe){
          chegouAoFim = true;
      }
      catch (OptionalDataException ode) {
          chegouAoFim = ode.eof; 
      }

      if (s != null) {
          quantosObjetos++;
          // Faz alguma coisa com seu User s (ex.: adicione-o a uma lista)
      }
  }
  readObject.close();

  System.out.println("Terminou. Eu li " + quantosObjetos + " objetos.");
  ```

  Dessa forma, basta o escritor ir mandando mais e mais objetos via `writeObject` (usando o mesmo `ObjectOutputStream`, é claro) e - quando terminar - simplesmente fechar a stream. A desvantagem dessa opção, como pode ver, é a necessidade de se fechar a stream no final; se você quer enviar N objetos mas manter a stream aberta para outras coisas, essa opção não se aplica.

Pessoalmente, iria com a opção 3, mas isso é subjetivo. Qualquer uma das quatro abordagens deve funcionar bem, escolha aquela com a qual se sinta mais confortável.

---

**Atualização:** exemplo completo (simplificado), abordando as questões de múltiplos clients, múltiplos objetos por client, e comunicação bidirecional:

Servidor.java

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1412);
while ( true )
    new ThreadRecebedor(serverSocket.accept()).start(); // Múltiplos clients por server
```

ThreadRecebedor.java

```
ObjectInputStream input;   // comunicação
ObjectOutputStream output; // bidirecional
User user;

public ThreadRecebedor(Socket socketCliente) {
    input = new ObjectInputStream(socketCliente.getInputStream());
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socketCliente.getOutputStream());
}

public void run() {
    while ( true ) {
        Object lido = input.readObject();
        if ( lido instanceof FimTransmissao )
            break;
        if ( lido instanceof User ) {
            user = (User)lido;
            output.writeUTF("Você me mandou:");
            output.flush(); // Nota: não sei se isso é mesmo necessário
            output.reset(); //       mas mal não deve fazer...
            output.writeObject(user);
            output.flush();
            output.reset();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Cliente.java

```
    Socket cliente = new Socket("192.168.1.7", 1412);
    User user = new User();
    user.setNome("Teste");
    user.setMsg("oi cristiano");
    user.setHora(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));

    ObjectOutputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

    // Envia o usuário
    output.writeObject(user);
    output.flush();
    output.reset();

    // Lê a resposta
    String resposta = input.readUTF();
    User u = (User).input.readObject();
    if ( !user.equals(u) )
        System.out.println("Servidor recebeu dados errados");

    // Envia mais objetos/Recebe mais respostas
    ...

    // Fim
    output.writeObject(new FimTransmissao());
    output.flush();
    output.reset();
    output.close();
```

Esse é um exemplo **bastante** simplificado: o servidor apenas lê objetos e responde ao seu tipo, e o client é quem manda coisas pra ele, de forma linear. Na prática, seria mais interessante estabelecer um **protocolo** - por exemplo mandando uma string (`writeUTF`) com um **comando** a ser executado remotamente, e em seguida um ou mais objetos como **parâmetros**. Ou melhor ainda: use o [padrão de design](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software) [**State**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/State). E para uma comunicação realmente bidirecional - onde tanto o client quanto o server podem iniciar uma mensagem - crie dois threads em vez de um, cada um com um loop infinito, sendo que um deles é responsável por ler e o outro por escrever. Gerenciar isso é complicado, e há considerações de performance envolvidas, sendo amplo demais pra abordar em uma única pergunta. Mas deixo a sugestão como ponto de partida.

Comment: O problema é que vou querer ficar "ouvindo o objeto chegar" e aí esbarra naquilo que te falei, onde instanciar? Onde prosseguir? Eu fiz um teste bem básico, vou postar junto com o código ali em cima.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Atualizei minha resposta de acordo com o que pude entender das suas dúvidas. Espero ter ajudado, mas é bom salientar que escrever um protocolo cliente/servidor é **bastante complicado** - assunto pra um capítulo de livro inteiro - de modo que dei um exemplo super-simples. Provavelmente, você vai esbarrar em mais dificuldades no futuro, por isso sugiro abrir perguntas novas cada vez que agarrar em alguma coisa. Considere também investigar frameworks já existentes pra cliente/servidor, de modo a não reinventar a roda (mas se seu objetivo for só aprender, então está tudo bem).

Comment: É, quero fazer mais para aprendizado mesmo. Agora tá tarde, amanhã vou verificar melhor o que você escreveu. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema reside no controle do seu *stream* de comunicação.

O seu método inicial de leitura de `string` e lendo do *stream* via `nextLine` é, na verdade, uma implementação de controle de fluxo bem simples e largamente utilizado, que faz uso de um conjunto de bytes específicos como delimitadores de carga (ou *payload)*. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que se traduz da seguinte maneira:

- Acumule todos os bytes que estão chegando via Socket.
- Ao encontrar os bytes `0x0D` `0x0A` (CR+LF):

  - Retire todos os bytes presentes no buffer até o marcador CR+LF;
  - Retorne os bytes removidos do buffer como uma string.

A sugestão de @mgibsonbr é excelente: Uma serialização de conteúdo em `XML` ou `JSON` permitiria que você continuasse utilizando CRL+LF como *late marker* para definição de payload (contanto que você, obviamente, impeça seus pacotes de possuir CR+LF em seus conteúdos.

Um outro método de controle, mais apropriado para conteúdo binário, é o *early marker*. Ao invés de esperar por uma eventual sequência de controle, este métódo informa ao *client* a quantidade de bytes a serem enviados e que caracterizam um payload. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo, o protocolo seria o seguinte:

- Receba dois bytes. A conversão deles para *Integer* indicará o tamanho do payload que será enviado.
- Acumule todos os bytes que estão chegando via Socket.
- Aguarde até o tamanho do conteúdo no buffer ser igual ao valor indicado pelo early marker. Aí,

  - retire o número de bytes indicados no early marker do buffer;
  - Retorne os bytes removidos como um array.
- Aguarde dois bytes, e repita o processo.

Este é o caso, por exemplo, do protocolo HTTP - que utilizar o header `content-size` para indicar quantos bytes compôem o *payload*, algo especialmente útil em conteúdo *multi-part*.